# Outputting two colums of dataframe into Django template using For Loop

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

I am trying to parse 2 columns of my dataframe(my_tweet_df) from views in Django to HTML document in Django tags i.e. '{% %}'. The dataframe is off Tweets data which I fetched from Tweepy. I hope for my output to look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      USERNAME       |       Tweet      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     @username1      |      tweet1      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     @username2      |      tweet2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       ......        |      ......      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

In my HTML page, code looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
      <th><h4>Username</h4></th>
      <th><h4>Tweet</h4></th>
   </tr>

   {% for key in my_tweet_df %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{key.author}}</td>
      <td>{{key.text}}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I do not know how to do so using for loop.
I have tried passing dataframe: `{% for key in dataframe %}` with `{{key.user}}` and `{{key.text}}`. I know this approach is not correct`enter code here` as it is looping through range of dataframe not values of one column.
I have tried converting to single columns and back to dataframe and passing like:
`my_tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(my_tweet_df.user, my_tweet_df.text)), columns=['username', 'status'])`
But that again doesn't work because it is a 2D arary now and has a range of 2 only.

Even if I try to pass them separately, I don't know how to do so using 2 for loops. I tried two for_loops because only separately the range will be full to print the column. But I am unable to I tried code so many different ways but I knew they would be wrong. Below is a failed attempt(i knew it was going to fail, showing as example):

```
   {% for key in text %}
   {% for key2 in author %}
      <tr>
         <td>{{key1}}</td>
         <td>{{key2}}</td>
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

But in the above approach I don't know how to use two for loops. In above code, I have not finished it as I it is evident it would not work. I am providing rest of my my code below. Code might be inconsistent as I have tried lots of things and it wasn't practical to show all so I am showing to give an idea.

```
tweets_user = my_tweet_df.user
tweets_text = my_tweet_df.text
```

```
context = {
   "my_tweet_df": my_tweet_df,
   "author": my_tweet_df.user,
   "text": my_tweet_df.text,
   "author": tweets_user,
   "text": tweets_text,
}
```

Following is my home_view of views.py. I have tried multiple DataTypes, so thats why you see so much unnecessary things as well.
My function `tweets, me = function.fetch_tweets()` returns out a dataframe in "tweets" variable with all sorts of data related to tweets such as status_id, tweet_text etc. While only user's own username is passed in "me" variable.

```
def home_view(request, id):

    tweets, me = function.fetch_tweets()
    # me = function.fetch_tweets.me()

    tweets_user = tweets.user
    tweets_text = tweets.text
    my_tweet_list = [' '.join(x) for x in zip(tweets_user,tweets_text)]
    # pd.DataFrame(my_tweet_list).to_csv("D:/Aun/Django Project/new_twitter/array.csv")
    # my_tweet_df = pd.DataFrame([my_tweet_list], columns=['username', 'status'])
    my_tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(tweets_user, tweets_text)), columns=['username', 'status'])
    # print(my_tweet_df)


    context = {
        "user": me,
        "my_tweet_list":my_tweet_list,
        "my_tweet_df": my_tweet_df,
        "tweets_df": tweets,

        "tweets": {
            'tweet_user': tweets.user,
            'tweet_tweet': tweets.text,
        },

        "tweet_list": [tweets.user, tweets.text],

        "author": tweets.user,
        "text": tweets.text,
        "id": tweets.id,
    }
    # context={}
    return render (request, 'tweet/home.html', context)
```

I am trying to render data in HTML document form a python list. The reason being that I am trying to stream live Tweets from Twitter using Tweepy. Just adding them onto my models and DB would be unnecessary. I do intend to add a model later to save the user's access_key and access_key_secret later but for now I am trying to print the list.

I am a fresh graduate with real experience and have just started to work on my first job. I know it might be very easy "for loop" solution but I can't seem to find a solution. I can't ask them as they can't put time away from the tasks assigned to them. Kindly help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add your model and view to your question ?

Comment: @barbaart I have added the view of my app but there is not model. The reason being that I am trying to stream live tweets. Just adding them onto my models and DB would be unnecessary. I do intend to add a model later to save the user's access_key and access_key_secret later but for now I am trying to print the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the perfect solution and I did not think I was able to explain my problem to the perfection but here is my solution or make shift solution that I was able to find out:

Here is the context{} dictionary my views.py file:

```
context = {
        "user": me,

        "author": tweets.user,
        "text": tweets.text,
        "id": tweets.id,
        "media": tweets.media_url,
        },
```

Here, 
user = username of account holder, 
author = username of person who tweeted, 
id = id of tweet,
media = url of images.

I created separate variables for each column rather than making them in a list and then I used them in a forloop. But here the problem was I needed to fetch individual values using index which is not currently supported easily in Django template. Here is my code in HTML template file:

`{% for item in 20|times %}`
I looped over them 20 times as 20 was the number of tweets I wanted to show on my page.
As I couldn't apple the counter to each entry separately, for now I had to come up with a make shift solution and that is

```
{% if forloop.counter == 0 %}
<td>{{author.0}}</td>
<td>
    <table class = "child">
        <tr><td>{{text.0}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="{{media.0}}" height="400"></td></tr>
            <div>
            <tr>
                <form method = "POST" action="{% url 'home' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" value="{{id.0}}" default ="{{id.0}}" name="tweet_id" id="tweet_id" readonly>
                    <input type="text" name="info_name" id="info_name" placeholder="Reply to Tweet" maxlength=280>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Reply">
                </form>
            </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </td>
{% endif %}
```

I repeated this for each row with total rows 20. It isn't good solution at all but it worked for now.
The form here is taking data and running a python script in views.py to reply to the tweet.

```
if not request.method == 'POST':
        return render (request, 'tweet/home.html', context)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    info = request.POST.get('info_name')
    status_id = request.POST.get('tweet_id')
    print('info')
    print('status_id')

    og_tweet = api.get_status(status_id) # Fetching tweet
    api.update_status(f"@{og_tweet.user.screen_name} {info}", og_tweet.id) # Replying

    return render (request, 'tweet/home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a quick example how to use a for loop with your context data;

Views.py:

```
def testpage(request):
    # first you need some data, from DB / API or else, but i just created a simple array:
    cars = [["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"], ['Opel', 'Toyota', 'Citroën']]
    # put this in the context variable:
    context = {'cars': cars}
    return render(request, 'testpage.html', context)
```

template testpage.html:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    {% for eachCar in car %}
        {{ eachCar }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

result in the template: `Ford Volvo BMW`

I am not sure where you getting your tweets from, but im sure you can loop over them if you do it like this.

Comment: I have an array with multiple two-dimensions and i am having trouble retrieving that. eg.
```cars = [[A1, A2, A3], [B1, B2, B3]]
```
I need to output this in the HTML document. That's why my and the above solution is not working.

Comment: i've updated my answer, is this what you need ? Another thing you can do is to specify the index of the arrays in your context, eg: context = { 'cars1': cars[0], 'cars2': cars[1] }